# Understanding what exactly 'self' means

Tags: objective-c, xcode, oop

I am having a hard time understanding how a particular code works so I went ahead and added the line

```
NSLog(@"%@ - %@", [self class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
```

at the start of every method in the hope that I will be able to see the exact sequence in which the various methods are invoked along with their class names.

However, at times `[self class]` is returning the name of a class in which the method is not actually present. For example, it shows the following in debug console -
PhotographersTableViewController - shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:, whereas, the method `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` is actually present in `CoreDataTableViewController`.

How can this happen?

P.S. Also, is there a way in Xcode to add a line in all the methods of a file?

Answer (score 4):

This is due to *inheritance*, which is fundamental to the way in which Obj-C, and most object-oriented programming languages, work. Glossing over details, this is how it works:

In all probability you have a declaration in your code like:

```
@interface PhotographersTableViewController : CoreDataTableViewController { ... }
```

This declares `PhotographersTableViewController` as an extension of `CoreDataTableViewController` - `PhotographersTableViewController` is said to *inherit* the methods of `CoreDataTableViewController`.

When you a method call:

```
PhotographersTableViewController *myPhotoView;
...
[myPhotoView shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation];
```

Then Obj-C first looks for the method `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` in class `PhotographersTableViewController`, which fails, and then in class `CoreDataTableViewController`, which succeeds - so it invokes the method defined in `CoreDataTableViewController` passing it the *current object*, i.e. the one referenced by the variable `myPhotoView`, as the value of the `self` argument (`self` is just an argument to the method supplied automatically by Obj-C).

This process is *fundamental* to inheritance and Obj-C.

Therefore when you print out the value of `self` you see the original object type.

The above glosses over a lot of detail, much of it very important: no mention of instance variables, hiding, scope, etc., etc. If you're learning Obj-C and object-oriented programming together you need to find a good book and read up on the details.

Answer (score 0):

If PhotographersTableViewController extends CoreDataTableViewController, then self is PhotographersTableViewController, even though the method exists in CoreDataTableViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Self is an instance that is accessing the current method.. And for the other ques.. I don't think there is such an option to put certain line in every method... You can try code snippets though